# strings and math operations in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am looking to fix some tables up using XSLT. I need to use the `Colspan` attribute but the code I am converting from uses `namest` and `nameend`.

example:

```
<entry namest="col1" nameend="col3">
```

I need to turn this into `<td colspan="3">`. I thought about setting variables and then using `substring($var,4,1)` to get the number at the end of the col3/col1 and then doing math the math- by subtracting the digit from namest from the digit from nameend and then adding one but it didn't work.

Comment: that should be easy, you have to match the attributes using "@", e.g. @col1. But give us a source XML and the XSLT you have so far - without that noone here can really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `entry` is the context node, the following expression returns the difference of the "col" values plus one which should be the colspan value you're looking for:

```
substring(@nameend, 4) - substring(@namest, 4) + 1
```

`substring(@attr, 4)` returns the substring of `@attr` starting from the fourth character until the end. The substrings are implicitly converted to numbers by the minus operator.

Test of the expression with libxslt's `xmllint`:

```
$ echo '<entry namest="col1" nameend="col3"/>' >so.xml
$ xmllint --shell so.xml 
/ > cd entry
entry > xpath substring(@nameend, 4) - substring(@namest, 4) + 1
Object is a number : 3
```